# How can i run docker commands inside a docker file?

Tags: docker, git-bash

I have this docker file:

```
# Use the official image as a parent image
FROM mysql/mysql-server:8.0

# Set the working directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the file from your host to your current location
COPY customers.sql .
COPY entrypoint.sh .

# Inform Docker that the container is listening on the specified port at runtime.
EXPOSE 1433:1433

# Run the command inside your image filesystem
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh

# Run the specified command within the container.
RUN /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

And entypoint.sh:

```
mysql --host=localhost --protocol=tcp -u root -pMypassword -e "create database customersDatabase; use customersDatabase; source customers.sql;"
```

but i get the following error message:

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (99)

when i run docker build

what is the correct way to build entrypoint.sh in order to run docker commands?

Comment: Are you trying to run a docker container within a docker container?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to create a script that will run a docker container that holds mysql instance

Comment: I think you are trying to run just the mysql-server instance, but you are trying to run it the same way you ran on your machine as a docker container, which obviously won't work. What is your intent for creating this Dockerfile?

Comment: My goal is to create a docker file that runs mysql instance and import a database,sql file to the mysql database.

Comment: Just do this without Docker.  Run the shell script on your host.  The machinations to package this in Docker are kind of complicated and since you're immediately going to "escape" back to running commands against the host Docker socket, you're not really getting any benefits from doing it in Docker.

Comment: I'm wan't to use docker file, but I'm getting the following: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (99)

Answer (score 0):

**BEFORE OP EDIT:**

**problem:**

```
./entrypoint.sh: line 2: docker: command not found
```

You are trying to run docker inside docker.

Possible solutions

```
1) Mount host's docker sock
```

or

```
2) Install docker inside docker before you run your
-> apt install docker.io
--> expect super size of your image
```

entrypoint

Difference between **1)** and **2)**

in **1)** your docker's docker is the host's docker

while in **2)** installed docker in the docker is independent and thus isolated from host

**AFTER OP EDIT**

**problem:**

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (99)
```

EDIT: And since you edit your question, which now doesnt correspond with your title, I will provide you with your second problem

You cannot connect to your localhost, because insider docker, localhost is docker itself, not your host.

- This can be solved by using host network driver.
- Or preferably, put your db in docker too, have in the same **docker network,expose port, name your db container as mysql_database, and connect to it as mysql_database:port**
- Or dont try to connect to db which is in your container from within your container. Thats I think antipattern. Usually it should be possible to get into db's CLI where you can run commands